# Counting solutions to extended MSO formulas, and sampling -- do these appear in the literature?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, lo.logic, treewidth

I am trying to determine if the literature contains various extensions of Courcelle's theorem. Since I haven't been able to find these in the literature, I guess that these are folklore results, or else false, since it seems that their proofs are only a few steps away from what appears in the literature already.

**Background:**

1) $EMS$ is an extension of $MSO$ that, among other things, allows the comparison of the cardinality of set variables. [See the discussion around definition 3.4 of this paper for a more precise description.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/019667749190006K)

It is proven [in the previously linked paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/019667749190006K) (Theorem 5.4) that $EMS$ decision problems are $XP$ in the tree-width.

2) It is proven in the same paper (Theorem 5.7) that $MSO$ counting problems are $FPT$ in the tree-width. (The definition of an enumeration problem appears on the top of page 317.)

**Question 1:** I think it is also true that $EMS$ counting problems are $XP$ in the tree-width. Does anyone know if this is explicitly stated anywhere in the literature?

**Proof sketch for the claim of question 1:** The broad steps of the argument should be the same as the proof of Theorem 5.7: one can polynomial time interpret the class of graphs of tree-width $\leq m$ into the class of rooted binary trees as described theorem 4.5. The transformation of an EMS problem $P$ on graphs into a corresponding EMS problem over binary trees induces a bijective correspondence of solution sets (remarks on page 322). Then, similarly to what is described prior to Theorem 5.7, the evaluation of the $MSO$ formula tree-automata on the labelled tree will be modified keep track of counts for the number of occurrences of all possible pairs of $(\text{tree automata state}, \text{evaluations})$ at each node of the tree. The total number of solutions can then be read off of the root by summing up the counts of all of the  $(\text{tree automata state}, \text{evaluations})$ pairs at the root node that satisfy the $EMS$ formula. This will be pseudopolynomial in the total (multiplicative) height of the coefficients of the evaluations, since one will need a tree-automata-states-many counters for *each* possible sub-evaluation. (The number of tree-automata-states is constant, since it is determined by the $MSO$ formula, but the number of sub-evaluations grows pseudopolynomially.)

Similarly:

**Question 2:** Likewise, one should obtain in the same way an algorithm for computing generating functions for the set of solutions to an EMS formula over some given weights, as in [this paper by Courcelle et al.](http://www.labri.fr/perso/courcell/CoursMaster/CMR-Dam.pdf). Does this appear in the literature anywhere?

**Question 3:** The same general kind of argument would show that it is possible to count the number of solutions to some formula $\phi(X,A,B)$ where $X$ is a free variable, and $A$ and $B$ are set-valued parameters, $FPT$ in tree-width if $\phi \in MSO_2$ or $XP$ in tree-width if $\phi \in EMS$ (with a constant that depends on the tree-width and $\phi$, not the choice of $A$ and $B$). In particular, by defining $\phi(X,A,B) = \psi(X) \wedge ( A \cap X = \emptyset) \wedge ( B \subseteq A)$, where $\psi \in MSO$ (resp. EMS), this means that one can make the necessary marginal counts in order to uniformly sample from the set of solutions to $\psi$ $FTP$ in tree-width (resp. $XP$ in tree-width). Similar (pseudopolynomial) statements for sampling from distributions of sets where probabilities are proportional to multiplying node/edge weights over the subset also ought to exist by similar reasoning. Does a statement like this about tree-width FPT/XP algorithms for MSO/EMS sampling problems appear in the literature anywhere?

Thank you for reading!